# Use jquery selector and events to call function in javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

ok I'm not sure if I'm doing this right so if I'm going about it all wrong please explain.

I have a javascript object which is drawing html based on ajax data.

I am then trying to use jquery to handle events on the html output from an instance of the above object. However I would like to call a function and get a property out of the instance of the javascript object which was used to draw the html.

so my code looks something like this:

```
function obj1 (){
    this.property1 = "propvalue";


    this.dosomething = function () {
        // does some processing
    }

   this.drawhtml = function () {
    // outputs html
   }

}

// jquery to handle events
 $(document).ready(function(){

// .edit is a class in the html outputted from the drawhtml
   $('body').on('click','.edit',function () {
     // call the dosomething from the object
     });

 });

// create instance of object could be multiple on on page
var instance1 = new obj1;

instance1.drawhtml();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the instance you created before:

```
// jquery to handle events
 $(document).ready(function(){

// .edit is a class in the html outputted from the drawhtml
   $('body').on('click','.edit',function () {
     instance1.dosomething();
     });

 });

// create instance of object could be multiple on on page
var instance1 = new obj1();  // added parentesis so it's valid javascript

instance1.drawhtml();
```

**EDIT**: Additional information starting from the comments:

The best way to handle this is to tie your event handler to the object itself. Something like this:

```
function obj1 (){
    this.property1 = "propvalue";


    this.dosomething = function () {
        // does some processing
    }

   this.drawhtml = function () {
       var elem = $("<div>my super dooper HTML</div>");
       elem.on('click', this.dosomething);
   }
```

}

Comment: Yep, your instance1 will be on the global scope. You can so use it inn a local jQuery scope without problem. However, why do you need to do something like that ?

Comment: that would work if I only had one of these object but what if I had 2

Comment: Then you would create an `instance2` and call the method on the appropriate instance

Comment: Im not sure I'm being very clear, both instances will create html which have a css class of .edit, say I created 2 instances I click the html output from instance1 how can I tell the event to run instance1.dosomething instead of instance2? The main aim here is I want to use the main object on many pages with slighly different details. So I intent to include the definition and jquery and just create an instance on each page maybe more than one and pass in the values which determind the difference when I run drawhtml.

Comment: I edited my answer. This is a different approach, but I think better suited for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi folks I cant get this working please see my jsfiddle it would appear that its alerting on load not on click as desired. http://jsfiddle.net/njzQL/

Comment: You should leave out the parenthesis after dosomething when you're attaching the event handler. You want to bind the function, not execute it. Please look at my answer for the correct syntax

Comment: @Kenneth Thank you ever so much you've really helped me :).